# Database issues when tried to migrate app from Appcelerator titanium to Native Java

Tags: java, android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've one app in Google Play that was developed using Appcelerator Titanium. It is a database driven app. Now I'm planning to write the app in Java and migrate it from Appcelerator to Java. Since the app is already available in the Play Store and it has a few active users, I don't want them to loose any of their data that is stored in the database. My issue is I don't know how to use the existing database created by the app which was developed using Appcelerator, in my new version which is going to be developed using native java.

In Appcelerator I'm initialising the database like:

```
var _db = Ti.Database.install('Database/DB/MyAppsDB','Database');
```

I tried to open it in java like:

```
String myPath = "/data/data/" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/Database/DB/MyAppsDB/Database"
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

But it doesn't work, it always returned `null`. How can I access the exact same database from my native app ? Please help, thanks in advance.